# TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentQuestions' of undefined in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, oop

I have the following code and what I am trying to do is to fetch some data from a database (which seems to be successful, I tried to log it), then arrange that data and send an array as a response. My class:

```
export class Controller {

    currentQuestions: IQuestionArranged[] = []; // This should be my array that I am trying to send as response

    constructor(){ }

    public async startNewGame(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): Promise<void> {
        let factory: RepositoryFactory = new RepositoryFactory();
        let repository: RepositoryInterface = factory.createRepository();

        let questionsFetched: IQuestionFetched[] = await repository.fetchQuestions();    // array of questions as they were fetched
        // let currentQuestions: IQuestionArranged[] = []; // <<<<<

        // forEach through fetched questions to arrange them
        questionsFetched.forEach(currentQuestion => {
            // check if the current question already exists in the array
            if (this.currentQuestions.filter(e => e.id == currentQuestion.questionId).length != 0) {
                // if yes -> find the question and add the new answer with its id
                this.currentQuestions
                    .filter(e => e.id == currentQuestion.questionId)
                    .map(e => e.answers.push({
                        id: currentQuestion.answerId,
                        answer: currentQuestion.answer
                    }));
            } else {
                // if no -> add the new question with the new answer
                this.currentQuestions.push({
                    id: currentQuestion.questionId,
                    question: currentQuestion.question,
                    answers: [{
                        id: currentQuestion.answerId,
                        answer: currentQuestion.answer
                    }]
                });
            }
        });
        res.send(this.currentQuestions);
    }
}
```

But I got this error that says "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentQuestions' of undefined" (full error description [here](https://pastebin.com/iPu1syqJ)). It seems to be working just fine if I use a local variable (the one marked with 5 left arrows as a comment) instead of the class property, which makes me think I am not using it properly but I do not know where my mistake is...

Comment: You are asking for debugging help which is [not a proper problem statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216018/how-to-handle-debug-my-code-for-me-questions). To answer your implicit question, you can fix `this` in `Array.forEach` by passing your context (i.e. the `Controller` instance on which `startNewGame` was called) as the second argument ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cleaner solution. What I had to do was to bind the "this" valiable like so:

```
constructor() {
   this.startNewGame = this.startNewGame.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the arrow function with a function expression? E.g =>

```
public startNewGame = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
 // Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This actually solves my problem. Although I still do not understand why my example fails, which definitely drives me crazy... Anyways, thanks again :)

Comment: The issue is related to the context of "this" variable. An arrow function does not have it's own "this". They use "this" value of the enclosing lexical scope.